# Onesignal Plugin Defer JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, deferred

Hi there I have a wordpress site with and I have defered scripts setup per the GT Metrix recommendations. All scripts are defered except for Onesignal Push Notification plugin,

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async></script>

function js_defer_attr($tag){

$scripts_to_exclude = array('.jsdelivr');

foreach($scripts_to_exclude as $exclude_script){
   if(true == strpos($tag, $exclude_script ) )
      return $tag;
}
   return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" onload src', $tag );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'js_defer_attr', 10 );
```

I am guessing it is adding script loading after page load/defering has been done?

Any help?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I did it on my websites and it is working fine... and more important page stuff will load first. The user experience is better this way.

I will explain what I did.

I changed the OneSignal plugin code and moved to another file all that code it ads to the header. A file is created at runtime when it does not exists.

Let's suppose I create a new file called "onesignal_deferred.js".

Then I added to the footer of the page:

```
function add_script(url){
   var element = document.createElement("script");
   element.src = url;
   document.body.appendChild(element);
}        
function downloadJSAtOnload(){
    add_script("add_script("https://<domain>/onesignal_deferred.js")
}
if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
```

The manifest is not necessary as well... as it is suited for older versions of Chrome... so it is a new optimization you can do to save one more request per page view.

I can also use this same function "add_script" to defer other scripts like Google Analytics and any other.

p.s.: when you defer Google Analytics, sometimes it will not count as a view a page that is closed before the Load Event... in this case you might be tricked by a false Google Analytics report saying that pages as loading faster. The case is that too slow loading pages will not be counted on...as Google Analytic script will not even be loaded.

Comment: "I changed the OneSignal plugin code" doesn't sound good :/ "any changes that you make directly into your plugin’s core files will be overridden when you update the plugin" [source](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/plugin-editor/)